# Parsing HTML with XPath/XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xpath, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to download an HTML page, and parse it using XMLHttpRequest(on the most recent Safari browser). Unfortunately, I can't get it to work!

```
var url = "http://google.com";

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", url);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
        response = xmlhttp.responseText;
        var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
        console.log(doc);
        var nodes = document.evaluate("//a/text()",doc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);
        console.log(nodes);
        console.log(nodes.snapshotLength);
        for(var i =0; i<nodes.snapshotLength; i++){
            thisElement = nodes.snapshotItem(i);
            console.log(thisElement.nodeName);
        }
    }
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

The text gets downloaded successfully(response contains the valid HTML), and is parsed into a tree correctly(doc represents a valid DOM for the page). However, nodes.snapshotLength is 0, despite the fact that the query is valid and should have results. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: Are you able to access via "normal" DOM? Also you can directly use `xmlhttp.responseXML`.

Comment: You can find answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729785/parsing-xmlhttprequest-result-using-xpath/40750779#40750779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using either:

- a JS library or
- you have a modern browser with the querySelectorAll method available (Safari is one)

You can try to use CSS selectors to parse the DOM instead of XPATH.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not XML. The two are not interchangeable. Unless the "HTML" is actually XHTML, you will not be able to use XPATH to process it.

Comment: I understand that - but Safari should be (and is, into the doc object) processing the "ugly" HTML into a nice, tidy, XHTML-compliant DOM, which should be able to be used with XPath, right?