# DOMParser not taking in IE 11

Tags: javascript

I've been working on removing XML Islands and ActiveX from a legacy system, bit it still needs to work in IE 11. I tried this simple example in onLoad but it bombs on new DOMParser(). I thought this was now supported in IE 11?

Is there an alternative to convert xml text returned by XHR to an xml doc? Thank you very much.

```
var parser, xmlDoc;
var text = "<bookstore><book>" +
"<title>Everyday Itzalian</title>" +
"<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>" +
"<year>2005</year>" +
"</book></bookstore>";
alert(text);
parser = new DOMParser();

alert("have parser");
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");


alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Comment: What does "it bombs" mean? Does it throw an error? Also you can just use `responseXML` to get an XML document from an XHR.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing XMLHttpRequest() result (using XPath)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729785/parsing-xmlhttprequest-result-using-xpath)

Comment: `xmlDoc` isn't declared - you need `var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString...`.

Comment: ok, more messing around. Formerly, XML data islands stored XML document. however, it appears the <script> or <div> tags I've seen as alternatives can't handle this, is that right? I can't stuff the responseXML object into an inline HTML element, mimicking the former XML data island?